# Need a count of one column if i am having another column values multiple

Tags: sql

I am having this query:

```
select  qos.orgname, qos.org, qos.suborg, qos.Archive, qos.location, count(c.coe) AS DEPT, c.coe AS DEP,
        qos.siteid, qos.admin as sitelead, 
        CASE When qos.Archive = 0 THEN 'Active' 
        when qos.Archive is null THEN '-'            
        ELSE 'Archived' 
        END AS STATUS
        from   qryOrgsite qos WITH (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT JOIN ltbcoe c WITH (NOLOCK) on qos.orgname = c.orgname and qos.location=      c.location
        group by qos.orgname, qos.location, qos.org, qos.suborg, qos.Archive, c.coe,
        qos.siteid, qos.ADMIN
```

This gives me some records as follows:
[image: records]

So i want the count of "Dept" column which are active. I mean it should return only one row with Organization B and Dept as 7....e.g here the Dept column should be 7.

that means I want count of c.coe column.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is your GROUP BY is too inclusive.  What the query is asking for is a count, but the results have to be unique by all of the columns in your GROUP BY.  If you only want a count per orgname, you will need to do

```
SELECT qos.orgname, COUNT(*)
FROM qryOrgsite qos
GROUP BY qos.orgname
```

This essentially says that you want to count all rows by the orgname.  Each column you add to the group by creates unique combinations for your COUNT.  For example, if you grouped by orgname and location it would give you a roll up count for each combination of those two columns.  Based on the data you show above this would result in

```
    OrganizationB    Demo-Fixe       1
    OrganizationB    GE CapitalP     3
    OrganizationB    Hadasa Plant    1
    OrganizationB    Mostoles Plant  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query in another:

```
select orgname, count(*)
from (
select  qos.orgname, qos.org, qos.suborg, qos.Archive, qos.location, count(c.coe) AS DEPT, c.coe AS DEP,
        qos.siteid, qos.admin as sitelead, 
        CASE When qos.Archive = 0 THEN 'Active' 
        when qos.Archive is null THEN '-'            
        ELSE 'Archived' 
        END AS STATUS
        from   qryOrgsite qos WITH (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT JOIN ltbcoe c WITH (NOLOCK) on qos.orgname = c.orgname and qos.location=      c.location
        group by qos.orgname, qos.location, qos.org, qos.suborg, qos.Archive, c.coe,
        qos.siteid, qos.ADMIN) t1
where t1.orgname = 'Organization B' and t1.STATUS = 'Active'
group by t1.orgname
```

Comment: It is throwing an error: 
Column 't1.orgname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

guys i have got the answer. 
I had to remove the department name from the group by and the select
because the count(c.coe) didnt had any effect.
Thanks for all you help